# Segmentation fault when trying to add elements of an array

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I'm trying to create a function that returns as its result the sum of the elements in the array. When I try to run the program, I get a segmentation fault. Could someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you!

```
int arraySum (int array[], int numberOfElements) {
int result = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
{
    result += array[i];
}

return result;
}

int main (void) {
int numberOfElements;
int *array = NULL;

printf("How many elements would you like in your array: ");
scanf("%i", &numberOfElements);

printf("\nPlease list the values of the elements in the array: ");

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
{
    scanf("%i", &array[i]);
}

int result = arraySum(array, numberOfElements);

return result;
}
```

Comment: You should look into `malloc`.

Comment: You can't assign values to memory that you haven't allocated. Use `malloc` or similar to allocate a chunk of memory, before you assign values to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is, that in C you need to manually allocate the memory if you are using a pointer instead of say a fixed-size array.

This is usually done by calling malloc, which will return a void-pointer (void*), which you need to cast to the desired type (in your case (int*)) before assigning it.

It is also important to note, that, when using malloc, you need to specify the amount of Bytes you want to allocate. This means that you can't just call it with the number of integers you want to store inside, but rather have to multiply that number with the amount of Bytes that one integer occupies (which depends on the Hardware and Operating System you use, hence you should use sizeof(int) for that purpose, which evaluates to that size at compile time).

I modified your code with a working example of how it could be done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int arraySum (int array[], int numberOfElements) {
    int result = 0;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
        result += array[i];
    }

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int numberOfElements;
    int *array = NULL;

    printf("How many elements would you like in your array: ");
    scanf("%i", &numberOfElements);

    array = (int*) malloc(numberOfElements * sizeof(int));

    printf("\nPlease list the values of the elements in the array: ");

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
        scanf("%i", &array[i]);
    }

    int result = arraySum(array, numberOfElements);

    printf("\n\nThe result is: %d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

You are also trying to return the result in your main function, but the return value of main in C is used to signal whether your program terminated without errors (signalled by a return value of 0) or didn't encounter any issues (any value other than 0).

Comment: Also, to clarify: The segmentation fault you're getting signals that you tried to access an illegal address in memory, which happens, since you didn't allocate any memory for your array and it points to NULL (which is an address that is illegal to dereference)

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory. It is not enough to just declare a pointer. You do it like this: `array=malloc(numberOfElements*sizeof(*array));`

Also, although it is possible to return `result` from the `main` function, you should not do that. The return value from `main` is usually used for error checking. Change the end of your program to

```
printf("Sum: %d\n", result);
return 0;
```

Returning 0 usually means that no error occurred.